# The method ____ is undefined by type ____?

Tags: java, android

I honestly don't understand this error. I have multiple classes with literally the same exact code but for some reason eclipse just doesn't like this one class in particular. The error is at **menu.loadResources()** and **menu.create()**

```
public void showSplash() {
    Debug.i("Scene: Splash");
    final SplashScene splash = new SplashScene();
    setCurrentScene(splash);
    splash.loadResources();
    splash.create();
    res.engine.setScene(splash);

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
            // TODO later load common resources here

            MenuScene menu = new MenuScene();
            menu.loadResources();
            menu.create();
            loadingScene = new LoadingScene();
            loadingScene.loadResources();
            loadingScene.create();
            // we want to show the splash at least SPLASH_DURATION miliseconds
            long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - timestamp;
            if (elapsed < MainActivity.SPLASH_DURATION) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(MainActivity.SPLASH_DURATION - elapsed);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Debug.w("This should not happen");
                }
            }
            setCurrentScene(menu);
            res.engine.setScene(menu);
            splash.destroy();
            splash.unloadResources();
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

**MenuScene Class:**

```
public class MenuScene extends AbstractScene{

    @Override
    public void loadResources() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {
        getBackground().setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override
    public void unloadResources() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

**However, I also have another class which is nearly the exact same code which doesn't give me an error:**

```
public class SplashScene extends AbstractScene{

    @Override
    public void loadResources() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void create() {
        getBackground().setColor(Color.PINK);
    }

    @Override
    public void unloadResources() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Any ideas?
Bump? I really need help figuring out what is wrong

Comment: Post the exact exception with full stack trace.

Comment: Do you have multiple classes named `MenuScene`? Are you sure?

Comment: I cannot post the stack trace because its an Android Application and won't let me run it without fixing the error. And yes, I only have one class named MenuScene

Comment: I am starting to consider if it is some sort of bug in Eclipse... However if it is just a bug and the code is fine, it doesn't help me much because Eclipse won't compile it until the errors are fixed -_-

Comment: 99.9999999999999999999999999% of the time the error is not in your tools, but in you and your code.

Comment: It looks like `loadResources()` doesn't do anything anyway. Why are you calling it in the first place?

Comment: I know, but as of right now I don't know why I would be getting this error and no one else has been able to give me an explanation

Comment: I'm going to modify it in the future. One step at a time. First I make sure the manager works, then I add stuff in all of the scenes

Comment: If you divulge the _exact_ error (aka logcat output) then we might be able to move forward.

Comment: Did you verify that you did not auto-import MenuScene from some other package by mistake?

Comment: Well I was able to fix it be renaming MenuScene to MenuScenes... I'm assuming that somewhere in the libraries there is a class called MenuScene? (which I never imported?)